# Python 3.6 Discord bot Bot events conflict

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

So I have two bot events
One that responds to the message "k" with "k"
and one that's a simple guess my number between 1-10 
The problem is that they conflict and only one works (the one that's below) IDK what I am missing. Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.author.bot: return
    if message.content==('k'):
        msg = 'k'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)

    await client.process_commands(message)




@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!guess'):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Guess a number     between 1 to 10')

        def guess_check(m):
            return m.content.isdigit()

        guess = await client.wait_for_message(timeout=10.0,    author=message.author, check=guess_check)
        answer = random.randint(1, 10)
        if guess is None:
            fmt = 'Sorry, you took too long. It was {}.'
            await client.send_message(message.channel,     fmt.format(answer))
            return
        if int(guess.content) == answer:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, 'You are right!')
        else:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Sorry. It is     actually {}.'.format(answer))

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

So How do I make it so they DON'T conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined the function `on_message()` twice.

To demonstrate the problem, what would you expect the output to be if I ran the following code?

```
def f(x):
    print(x)

def f(x):
    print('Nothing useful')

f(3)
```

The same issue is present in your code.

Assuming the discord framework will call a function called `on_message()` when a message is received, you need to have *one* `on_message()` function that handles *any* input.  As such, it will look like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content==('k'):
        ...

    if message.content.startswith('!guess'):
        ...
```

If you're feeling particularly snazzy, you can break out the contents of the `if` blocks into their own functions, to make the script easier to read, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you, once you have the rest of it working.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it and you went above and beyond what I was expecting thank you. That insight really makes a lot of sense,

Comment: If I solved your problem, please do mark it as the accepted answer.  It gives me those sweet sweet stack overflow points.  :D